# Take an unique array from list of arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have following array, i need to get unique arrays, or **set union** (same things only once) from the list of arrays and also exclude empty arrays. How can this be achieved on the server side ?

```js
{
    "slots": [
        [],
        ["08:30AM", "08:40AM", "08:50AM", "09:00AM", "09:10AM", "09:20AM", "09:30AM", "09:40AM", "09:50AM", "10:00AM", "10:10AM", "10:20AM", "10:30AM", "10:40AM", "10:50AM", "11:00AM", "11:10AM", "11:20AM", "11:30AM"],
        ["08:30AM", "08:40AM", "08:50AM", "09:00AM", "09:10AM", "09:20AM", "09:30AM", "09:40AM", "09:50AM", "10:00AM", "10:10AM", "10:20AM", "10:30AM", "10:40AM", "10:50AM", "11:00AM", "11:10AM", "11:20AM", "11:30AM"],
        ["08:30AM", "08:40AM", "08:50AM", "09:00AM", "09:10AM", "09:20AM", "09:30AM", "09:40AM", "09:50AM", "10:00AM", "10:10AM", "10:20AM", "10:30AM", "10:40AM", "10:50AM", "11:00AM", "11:10AM", "11:20AM", "11:30AM"],
        [],
        [],
        []
    ],
    }
```

I need the output as,

```js
{
    "slots": [
        ["08:30AM", "08:40AM", "08:50AM", "09:00AM", "09:10AM", "09:20AM", "09:30AM", "09:40AM", "09:50AM", "10:00AM", "10:10AM", "10:20AM", "10:30AM", "10:40AM", "10:50AM", "11:00AM", "11:10AM", "11:20AM", "11:30AM"]
}
```

Comment: Show what have you done. This is not a place for throwing your work to other people. Also add more tags like C, C++, javascript, java, function, php and python and other.

Comment: @SalvadorDali While I aggree with the "don ask others to do your work" sentiment. There **is** a clear way to do this with MongoDB, so you **do not** want to do this client side in code so those tags are irrelevant. As is the hold for this reason. Consider that not everyone speaks English perfectly.

Comment: Probably helps if my English is better than my typing: "Don't ask others to do your work". But this may be a lack understanding where to start. The edited content of the question should be clear enough for the MongoDB answer to be given.

Answer (score 1):

The result can be acheived by the use of the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method, which allows pipeline operations to act on the element to "re-form" the data. The most important operator here is [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/), which keeps only the "unique/same" elements:

```js
db.slots.aggregate([

    // Unwind the "slots" array
    { "$unwind": "$slots" },

    // Unwind the "inner" arrays
    { "$unwind": "$slots" },

    // Compose a "set" of the results
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "slots": { "$addToSet": "$slots" } 
    }},

    // Just return the "set"
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "slots": 1 }}
])
```

Note that a "set" is not considered to be ordered by the internals of the engine. If you **need** the results to be ordered then you can [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) again, sort the results and re-group. As follows:

```js
db.slots.aggregate([

    // Unwind the "slots" array
    { "$unwind": "$slots" },

    // Unwind the "inner" arrays
    { "$unwind": "$slots" },

    // Compose a "set" of the results
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "slots": { "$addToSet": "$slots" } 
    }},

    // Unwind the "set" result
    { "$unwind": "$slots" },

    // Sort the results
    { "$sort": { "slots": 1 } },

    // Group the array again
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "slots": { "$push": "$slots" } 
    }},

    // Just return the "set"
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "slots": 1 }}
])
```

You should be very careful with storing nested arrays like this. Unless you **specifically** need then for a special purpose, then they are notoriously difficult to query and update.